# Append the results of a function call on a vector to one another in r

Tags: r, function, append

I have a 1 column dataframe with a series of URLs in its only column (could be a vector just the same). For the sake of this example, we'll keep each URL the same:

```
urls<-as.data.frame(c("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_counties_in_California", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_counties_in_California","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_counties_in_California"))
colnames(urls)<-"col1"
urls$col1<-as.character(urls$col1)
```

I also have a function I have written that scrapes a table from those urls:

```
wiki_scrape <- function(x){
  x_url <- x %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[2]') %>%
    html_table() %>%
    .[[1]] %>%
    select(County)
  return(x_url) 
}
```

The result of `wiki_scrape(urls[1,1])` is a dataframe of 58 observations. I would like to run this function `wiki_scrape` in an iterative fashion over the entire vector `urls` (and not just `urls[1,1]`) and append each resulting dataframe to the previous resulting dataframe. In this example, `urls` has 3 urls listed so I want my resulting dataframe to be 174 observations long (3*58 = 174 with 58 being the length of one dataframe scraped using `wiki_scrape`).

Comment: You don't mean do.call(rbind .., do you? (`do.call(rbind, lapply(urls, wiki_scrape))`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
library(dplyr)

map(urls$col1, wiki_scrape) %>% bind_rows() 

#            County
#1   Alameda County
#2    Alpine County
#3    Amador County
#4     Butte County
#5 Calaveras County
#6    Colusa County
#....
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map_df` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
out <- map_df(urls$col1, wiki_scrape)
head(out)
#            County
#1   Alameda County
#2    Alpine County
#3    Amador County
#4     Butte County
#5 Calaveras County
#6    Colusa County
```